# Anyone interested in helping improve the close process?

Tags: discussion

There's a post on MetaStackOverflow which is relevant to us: [Help us make "Off-Topic" close reasons clearer to the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169814/195988) (although the discussion there is mostly focused on technology-type questions). Head over there to see what's being discussed, and have a say if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I, too, would like to see the rationale for closure more clearly communicated. Do understand that is easier said than done.